# HTA WScript.shell .Run to store to file, not working?

Tags: cmd, jscript, hta

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

I want to run a command line tool from an HTA and capture the output to a file so I can process it after...but it's not writing any file...

If I type `adb devices > c:\adb.txt` into the Windows Command Prompt, it works, but if I use the following JScript code in the HTA, the adb program runs, I get a return code of 0, but no output file is created.

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var runcmd = "adb devices > c:\\adb.txt";
var oExec = oShell.Run(runcmd, 0, true);
```

Is there something wrong with my script that I'm missing?

Comment: Don't use the `.Run` method but the `.Exec` method to read write the input/output/error streams directly without the need to store to a file. IIRC with the .Run method you need to run cmd.exe to have redirection.

Comment: The second line of your code should be like this : `var runcmd = "Cmd /c adb devices > c:\\adb.txt";`